# AMPscript: Automating Email Creation and Personalization

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

I am looking to automate and personalize the creation of my emails in Email Studio by using AMPscript (I am just learning how to write AMPscript). I want to be able to use a data extension containing an image url, product name, price, description, etc. and calling these into an email.

For now, I am just testing with a regular data extension. My code is as follows:

```
%%[ VAR @targetSubsetor, @industry
set @industry = Industry
IF not Empty(@industry) then
  set @lookupValue = AttributeValue("Industry")
  set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("SFDE_DE_Intern",3,"[First Name] desc, Email asc","Industry",@lookupValue)
    FOR @i = 1 TO @countDE DO
      set @row = Row(@rows, @i)
      set @targetSubsetor = Field(@row,"Subsetor")
    NEXT @i
ENDIF ]%%
```

The above code is for creating the array based on one attribute- the target industry.

I also set a default in case none match the attribute. The code is below:

```
%%[ set @defaultRows = Lookup("SFDE_Intern", @numRowsToReturn,"[First Name] desc, Email asc","Industry", Saúde)
VAR @countDE set @countDE = RowCount(@rows)
IF (@numRowsToReturn != 0) AND (@countDE < @numRowsToReturn) THEN
  VAR @remainder, @j
  set @remainder = Subtract(@numRowsToReturn,@countDE)
  FOR @j = 1 TO @remainder DO
    set @row = Row(@defaultRows, @j)
    set @targetSubsetor = Field(@row,(@remainder + @j))
  NEXT @j
ENDIF ]%%
```

I am trying to call the variable with inline AMPscript:

```
%%=v(@targetSubsetor(1))=%%
```

I am getting errors when I try testing it:

> The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again.
>   HTML Version
>   There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative.
>    Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid
> An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail.
>    Script Expression: Lookup("SFDE_Intern", @numRowsToReturn,"[First Name] desc, Email asc","Industry", Saúde)
>
> The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client.
>    Function Call: Lookup("SFDE_Intern", @numRowsToReturn,"[First Name] desc, Email asc","Industry", Saúde)
>    Attribute or Field Name: Saúde
>    
> Invalid Content: 
> set @defaultRows = Lookup("SFDE_Intern", @numRowsToReturn,"[First Name] desc, Email asc","Industry", Sa&#ú;de)
>   Text Version
>   There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative.
>    Error 1: Script SET Statement Invalid
> An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail.
>    Script Expression: Lookup("SFDE_Intern", @numRowsToReturn,"[First Name] desc, Email asc","Industry", Saúde)
>
> The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client.
>    Function Call: Lookup("SFDE_Intern", @numRowsToReturn,"[First Name] desc, Email asc","Industry", Saúde)
>    Attribute or Field Name: Saúde
>    
> Invalid Content: 
> set @defaultRows = Lookup("SFDE_Intern", @numRowsToReturn,"[First Name] desc, Email asc","Industry", Sa&#ú;de)

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I updated my code and questions after looking at the resources in the comments.

Comment: You Need to select a row from these rows you cannot simply print a rows. Search for examples with row and rows, just try to search for it. And when you have a row you want to select a field from that row.

Comment: [The AMPscript 401 article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/AMPscript401.htm) goes over what you'll need in this scenario (e.g., looping through a rowset), but because you're new, I'd recommend going through the other three articles in the series first starting at 101 (they're not too long).

Comment: @MarkG thanks for the article, it helped a lot. However, I am still stuck on creating an array using a for loop; I want to later call the specific rows of the array. 
Would you know how to fix this?

Comment: @GS you've already created your "array" or rows -- it was stored to the `@rows` variable. The article then shows you how to loop through your array or rows... find the following line: `for @i = 1 to RowCount(@rows) do` and just modify your `Field()` arguments to match the fields in your data extension.